# How to know if the user is dropping the file on the defined location?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

On this application, the user can drag and drop a file on the specified location. Let say here:

```
<div id="dropZone" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

However, we noticed that no matter where the file is drop, the webpage will process it. Here is an example taken online https://jsfiddle.net/oL2akhtz/. There is a place to drop the file, but no matter where you leave it, it will stay. How to know if the user is droping the file in the right place?  Or how do you disable the cursor if the user is not droping the file where it should be?

Comment: it actually only work on the dropzone because it has full width and height

Comment: Your dropzone is covering the entire page!!

Comment: This is another example, where the dropzone is defined, but the file can be dropped anywhere. `https://codepen.io/prasanjit/pen/NxjZMO`.

Answer (score 0):

it actually only works on the dropzone because it has full width and height.
and the drag is set to `window`, when a user drags over the window, the div will be visible but will not receive any files

to fix it

1. Optimize the height and width:

```
div#dropZone {
  background: gray;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: 0.6;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

2. I'm not sure, but if you tried to fix it by allowing and denying the user from dropping it outside the drag area, delete the functionality because it's useless.